# VBA, Delimit by fixed width with given width's

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to put a fixed width into a code? It is very tedious doing this manually.

Having trouble with this,

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth _
, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 5), Array(6, 20), Array(21, 55), Array(56, 57)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Nothing is happening when I run this. What am I doing wrong?Any help would be appreciated.

An example of how I want it delimited:

```
stackoverflow
```

to

```
stack (1:5) Overflowflow (6:2) in 2 columns.
```

i have the following width's:

```
POSITION(1:5),
POSITION(6:20),
POSITION(21:55),
POSITION(56:67),
POSITION(68:72),
POSITION(73:84)
POSITION(85:96)
POSITION(97:99),
POSITION(100:102),
POSITION(103:127),
POSITION(128:152),
POSITION(153:155),
POSITION(156:158),
POSITION(159:159),
POSITION(160:160),
POSITION(161:174),
POSITION(175:199),
POSITION(200:203),
POSITION(204:204),
POSITION(205:205),
POSITION(206:206),
POSITION(207:207),
POSITION(208:221),
POSITION(222:233)
POSITION(234:247),
POSITION(248:261),
POSITION(262:273)
POSITION(274:298),
POSITION(299:312),
POSITION(313:326),
POSITION(327:340),
POSITION(341:375),
POSITION(376:410),
POSITION(411:415),
POSITION(416:427)
POSITION(428:452),
POSITION(453:477),
POSITION(478:478),
POSITION(479:492),
POSITION(493:504)
POSITION(505:529),
POSITION(530:533),
POSITION(534:534),
POSITION(535:546)
POSITION(547:558)
POSITION(559:566),
POSITION(567:571),
POSITION(572:596),
POSITION(597:597)
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: to Delimit column A , all the data is in Col A, I want to them to do into separate columns using the above fixed width numbers.

Comment: "If the source data has fixed-width columns, the first element of each two-element array specifies the starting character position in the column (as an integer; 0 (zero) is the first character). The second element of the two-element array specifies the parse option for the column as a number from 1 through 9, as listed above."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel

Comment: any help with a vba script on delimiting fixed width?